# Asp.Net 5 (MVC) RedirectToAction() how to make RestFul route

Tags: asp.net-core

(First StackOverflow post + MVC6 noob)

Using Asp.Net 5 MVC 6 rc-1

I want my Controller successful Create POST action to redirect to the Edit GET action in the same controller. The controller is in an Area. When I call the following code using the RedirectToAction method, the resulting url always has a querystring argument "../Edit?id=3" instead of the the RestFul path. "../Edit/3". I tried with a specific routemap definition, but it made no difference. Is there a way to create the RestFul "../Edit/3" route?
Thank you.

..
routes.MapRoute(name: "Edit",
                template: "{area}/{controller}/Edit/{id}");
does not make a difference..

Example code:

In Startup.cs:

```
..
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
          ..
          app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
          ..
 }
..
```

Controller class:

```
[Area("Administration")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]/")]
public class PersonController : Controller
{
..    
     [HttpGet]
     [Route("Edit/{Id:int}")]
     public IActionResult Edit(int id)
     {
..

     [HttpPost]
     [Route("[action]")]
     public IActionResult Create(PersonViewModel viewModel)
     {
         ..
         return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = newPersonId}); 
     }
..
```

Comment: Is there any reason, other than aesthetic reasons, that it makes a difference?

Comment: Nick, Yes, the reason is probably more for aesthetic and applying RestFul routes rather than technical in this case, but I would still like to know if this is possible for future reference. To get me going, I will create an additional Edit method to handle the query string 'route' for now. Thanks.

Comment: No need to create a new method, etc. The following change to the Edit method HttpGet attribute decoration works. This is the new method decoration.

Comment: `[HttpGet("Edit")]
[Route("Edit/{Id:int}")]
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{..`

Comment: (Note: This will make it work with both the RestFul and the query string routes..)

Comment: Appologies ../Edit/3 is of course not proper RestFul perhaps I should have written "RestFul" rather.. :/